# How to attach normal Phone handset to jack 3.5

Tags: microphone, telephone, cellphone

I have this Question :

How can I attach the normal phone handset to jack 3.5 to use with my cell phone?

For example : there is a product, http://www.cellphoneshop.net/redtel.html

Could someone give me DIY How-To ? I want to do it all by myself.

I'm Noob in electronics Fields , please explain to me simply.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @passerby and @Tom have very correctly noted...

That product isn't an old telephone. Those would require an audio amplifier and microphone pre-amplifier to get levels that would work with your cell phone.

But, if you do have an old phone, do as @passerby suggested:

1. Open it up,
2. remove all the electronics you find in there,
3. replace them with the electronics from a [cheap wired headset](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002WVDJNU).

Answer (score 2):

What they sell is no normal handset as it is known from old phones, it is just a normal hands-free equipment wrapped (3$ in every store) in lots of plastic.

Answer (score 1):

The simple method: Take a wired headset, take it apart. Take a telephone handset, take it apart. Put the wired headset in the telephone handset. Screw it back together. http://hackaday.com/2009/12/23/bluetooth-handset-hacks/

There really isn't much to it. Maybe at most you need to unsolder some wires and add in a longer one or use some hotglue to hold it in place. Then again, you can get these for like 12 dollars at a big box store like Sears at this point.